# Facebook Comments: get comment with more likes

Tags: json, facebook, comments, facebook-like

I wont to get the best comment of a page

1. - more like
2. - more old

from:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[YOUR PAGE]

i get this result:

{"[YOUR PAGE]": {

```
  "comments": {
     "data": [
        {
           "id": "10150129443959608_15887865",
           "from": {
              "name": "Trent Seed",
              "id": "614130500"
           },
           "message": "that house is huge!!",
           "created_time": "2011-04-13T10:00:44+0000"
        },
        {
           "id": "10150129443959608_15902791",
           "from": {
              "name": "Mitch Seed",
              "id": "688036079"
           },
           "message": "wtf this is ridiculous! I cant believe this is actually right by us.",
           "created_time": "2011-04-14T02:17:18+0000",
           "comments": {
              "data": [
                 {
                    "id": "10150155952624608",
                    "from": {
                       "name": "Ethan Ming",
                       "id": "592969356"
                    },
                    "message": "where does all that flat land come from in los altos HILLS? oh i guess that $100 million also went to removing a small mountain too",
                    "created_time": "2011-04-14T02:43:57+0000"
                 },
                 {
                    "id": "10150155954519608",
                    "from": {
                       "name": "Mitch Seed",
                       "id": "688036079"
                    },
                    "message": "yeah haha thats just straight ridiculous i have ran all through los altos hills i dont remember any land like this haha",
                    "created_time": "2011-04-14T02:46:40+0000"
                 },
                 {
                    "id": "10150155969784608",
                    "from": {
                       "name": "Leila Marie",
                       "id": "1044030343"
                    },
                    "message": "jus copied you haha this is crazy",
                    "created_time": "2011-04-14T03:13:07+0000"
                 }
              ],
              "count": 3
           }
        },
        {
           "id": "10150129443959608_15932966",
           "from": {
              "name": "Arthur Lozinski",
              "id": "1044030063"
           },
           "message": "digital sky technologies. remember that name :-D",
           "created_time": "2011-04-15T15:42:23+0000"
        },
        {
           "id": "10150129443959608_15962947",
           "from": {
              "name": "Brian Sator",
              "id": "513517991"
           },
           "message": "I feel like I would get lost in that place.",
           "created_time": "2011-04-17T08:03:24+0000",
           "likes": 1
        },
        {
           "id": "10150129443959608_16282803",
           "from": {
              "name": "Jordan McDaniel",
              "id": "506352386"
           },
           "message": "holy shit",
           "created_time": "2011-05-04T04:29:27+0000",
           "comments": {
              "data": [
                 {
                    "id": "10150172606879608",
                    "from": {
                       "name": "Davey Nicholas",
                       "id": "1346961549"
                    },
                    "message": "\"no plans to move into the mansion\" whos' tryina squat",
                    "created_time": "2011-05-04T04:35:16+0000"
                 }
              ],
              "count": 1
           }
        }
     ],
     "paging": {
        "next": "[link]"
     }
  }
```

}
}

i wont to get the best message of the json file (or is possible in other way?)

Answer (score 0):

try fql

> SELECT id,text,likes FROM comment WHERE object_id=[page_id] order by likes desc

with graphs

> https://graph.facebook.com/fql=SELECT+id,text,likes+FROM+comment+WHERE+object_id=[page_id]+order+by+likes+desc

[see more about fql](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)